# Selecting distinct values from XSLT sub query

Tags: xslt

I have this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <properties>
    <property name="prop1" type="type1"/>
    <property name="prop2" type="type2"/>
    <property name="prop3" type="type3"/>
    <property name="prop4" type="type1"/>
  </properties>
  <types>
    <type name="type1" group="group1"/>
    <type name="type2" group="group1"/>
    <type name="type3" group="group2"/>
    <type name="type4" group="group3"/>
  </types>
  <groups>
    <group name="group1" owner="owner1"/>
    <group name="group2" owner="owner2"/>
    <group name="group3" owner="owner3"/>
  </groups>
</metadata>
```

I am transforming it using this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="docRoot" select="/" />
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($docRoot/metadata/properties/property/@type)">
      <xsl:variable name="groupOwner" select="$docRoot/metadata/groups/group[@name=$docRoot/metadata/types/type[@name=current()]/@group]/@owner" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$groupOwner"/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I want to do is print out the list of unique group owners for all of the properties in the document. I'm successfully filtering out duplicate types with `distinct-values` but can't see how to filter out duplicate owners.

The current output:

```
owner1
owner1
owner2
```

The required output:

```
owner1
owner2
```

If it helps no two groups have the same owner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys can be your friend here...

```
<xsl:key name="types" match="type" use="@name" />
<xsl:key name="groups" match="group" use="@name" />
```

Then you can do this, without even any need for `distinct-values` because you won't get duplicate nodes returned this way:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('groups', key('types', metadata/properties/property/@type)/@group)">
```

For example, try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:key name="types" match="type" use="@name" />
  <xsl:key name="groups" match="group" use="@name" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', key('types', metadata/properties/property/@type)/@group)">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@owner, '&#10;')" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In fact, you can simplify the `xsl:for-each` to this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('groups', key('types', metadata/properties/property/@type)/@group)/@owner" separator="&#10;" />
```

Comment: Thanks, much simpler and I might even understand it

Answer (score 1):

Ah, just needed to try a bit harder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="docRoot" select="/" />
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($docRoot/metadata/groups/group[@name=$docRoot/metadata/types/type[@name=$docRoot/metadata/properties/property/@type]/@group]/@owner)">
      <xsl:value-of select="current()"/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Open to any suggestions for simplifying this though!

Comment: You could potentially simplify this with the use of `xsl:key`. I've added an answer to show how this could be done.